# GraphHopper: use shape file to create graph for routing

Tags: shapefile, graphhopper

I am evaluating GraphHopper for calculate routes. From what I read, it is surely going to be my choice, specially because it has various algorithms and also web API. However, GraphHopper works with OSM format, and the data that I have is in a big shape file (~1 Gb) and has its own fields which specify the type of the road, its direction, etc. I think it it would require writing a reader for shape file (like OSMRader). Some have suggested using a converter to convert shape file into OSM format and use that with GraphHopper. But I have a few questions I hope I could get answers to:

(1) Is there a ShapeReader that I could use readily - that will be most useful.

(2) If I use converter to create OSM from shape file, how would GraphHopper know about the semantics of the field values coming from the shape file?

(3) If I write my own ShapeReader, is there any documentation that can help me - such as what bare minimum needs to be implemented to make shape file work with GraphHopper?

Comment: Re (1) There is currently no ShapeReader, please open an issue for this. Re (2) I don't know. Re (3) Also there are some tests but I fear no docs. Although you can read the developer docs and ask on the mailing list if something is unclear.

Answer (score 1):

Converting my comment into an answer:

Re (1) There is currently no ShapeReader, please open an issue for this.

Re (2) I don't know.

Re (3) Also there are some tests but I fear no docs. Although you can read the developer docs and ask on the mailing list if something is unclear

Comment: Is the answer valid till date?